# PyDrake SNOPT Print Log

Tags: jupyter-notebook, drake

How can I get the SNOPT print file to display from PyDrake in a Jupyter Notebook?

This user guide, http://www.ccom.ucsd.edu/~peg/papers/sndoc7.pdf, mentions a "Print file" option which I have tried to turn to `true` with

```
mp.SetSolverOption(SolverType.kSnopt, "Print file", 1)
```

but this doesn't seem to have done anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
prog.SetSolverOption(SolverType.kSnopt, 'Print file', "/tmp/snopt.out")
```

Comment: Thanks!
Should this output to a file "/tmp/snopt.out"? It doesn't look like this file was created.

Comment: Yes.  (Greg points out that you might not have access to that directory in docker, so you could try a local directory instead)